# need to get the 'a' name for each .post for the plugin

Tags: jquery, loops, plugins, each

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    var url = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
    var post = $('.post').children('a[name]').attr('name');

    var helpers = {
        "defaults": {
            "post": post,
            "href": url+'#',
            "send": 'true',
            "layout": 'button_count',
            "width": '125',
            "faces": 'false',
            "font": 'verdana',
            "action": 'like',
            "scheme": 'light',
        },

        "init": function (options) {
            var settings = $.extend({}, helpers.defaults, options),

            easyface = $('<div />').addClass('easyface fb-like').attr({
                "data-href": settings.href + settings.post,
                "data-send": settings.send,
                "data-layout": settings.layout,
                "data-width": settings.width,
                "data-show-faces": settings.faces,
                "data-font": settings.font,
                "data-action": settings.action,
                "data-colorscheme": settings.scheme
            });

            return this.each(function (i, elem) {
                var self = $(elem),                 
                data = self.data('easyface');  
                if (!data) {   
                    self.data('easyface', easyface);
                    self.append(easyface);
                }
            });
        },

        "destroy": function () {
            return this.each(function (i, elem) {
                var self = $(this),                
                data = self.data('easyface');   // test to see if we've already called init on this element

                $(window).unbind('.easyface');      // unbind any namespaced events, assuming you've namespaced them like "click.easyface"
                self.removeData('easyface');        // remove the data flag
                self.find('.easyface').remove();    // remove the appended div
            });
        }

    };

    //define the method "easyface"
    $.fn.easyface = function (method) {
        if (helpers[method]) {
            // call the method and pass in the settings
            return helpers[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            // default to the init method and pass in the arg
            return helpers.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            // throw an error
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip');
        }
    };
}(jQuery));

$(function() {
    $('body').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=477049588983712";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
});
```

I think the issue lies here

```
var url = window.location.href.split('#')[0];
var post = $('.post').children('a[name]').attr('name');
var helpers = {`
```

Whats happening is it is coming up with the url like this -

*http://www.easybbtutorials.com/t177-user-profile-home-page#1244#undefined*

so I added the `split('#')[0];` and that worked well but I am still getting the undefined part.

*http://www.easybbtutorials.com/t177-user-profile-home-page#undefined*

Also in each of the `.post` where this is it is the same url for each of the fb likes it needs to add each parents `a` name ...

I may come off confusing how I said it but I'm just furious right now and writing fast.

Better explaination:

1. .post is the first one and the fb data-href should be `http://www.easybbtutorials.com/t177-user-profile-home-page#8870`
2. .post is the second one and the fb data-href should be `http://www.easybbtutorials.com/t177-user-profile-home-page#8871`
3. .post is the third one and the fb data-href should be `http://www.easybbtutorials.com/t177-user-profile-home-page#8872`
4. .post is the fourth one and the fb data-href should be `http://www.easybbtutorials.com/t177-user-profile-home-page#8873`

So on and so forth, this is a forum so there will be multiple .post areas

**As of now I have to write the call like so...**

```
$('.post').each(function() {
   $(this).easyface();
  });
```

I want the plugin to automatically do each anything really. so `$('.post').easyface()` will automatically do the code like above.

Also I need it to as of now get the `('a[name]').attr('name');` of each post as well, though I've had to add it like this now, `('a[name]').attr('name').split('p')[1];` because all the id's start with p ex: p830 p338 p395 p standing for post. And given links won't recognize #p784 so it needs to become #784.

Who ever can get this working can have all of my reputation that is set at 100... now I only have 43, but whatever waited too long for this.

BETTER UNDERSTANDING HERE::

http://jsfiddle.net/zUeFL/17/

As you can see I have four likes and send, like one they all like. Need a different url for each post.

Comment: Instead of useless edits just to get points, it may help to actually do something. you fixed ignorant things like worked well? I was saying it like this  /  well...worked.  Geesh you editors just have so much time on your hands to try and earn edit points pfft

Comment: Can you post the HTML contents of an example `.post` div?

Comment: Yes I'll post the fiddle I had which i just grabbed the html from my site of it.  http://jsfiddle.net/zUeFL/9/

Comment: Waiting for an answer any one?

Comment: Need this to work ASAP I am putting a bounty on this with as much as I can :/

Comment: @EasyBB Where is your HTML code? In the jsFiddle, which button should I press to test this?

Comment: @EasyBB I've read your post multiple times and am still unclear on what your question is. Please take a moment to reread and possibly revise the post to make it as concise as possible: Here's the problem, this is what it does, this is what i want it to do.

Comment: @EasyBB What do you expect as the value of `post` after this: `"post": $('.post').children('a[name]').attr('name')`. Is it an array of values, like `['8870', '8871']` ?

Comment: sorry fixed the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zUeFL/14/

Comment: @EasyBB Where do I get the output in the jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? The plugin would be located at the bottom of the fiddle of the generated html. It's facebook plugin that I started creating...

Answer (score 3):

**Issue 1:**

```
var post = $('.post').children('a[name]').attr('name');
```

`children()` will return a list of elements.

**Issue 2:**

Just run the plugin from inside a `$(document).ready` block.

**Solution**

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //run the plugin

    pNames = []

    $('.post').children('a[name]').each(function() {
        pNames.push($(this).attr('name'));
    });

    $('.postfoot').easyface({
        "post": pNames
    });
});
```

**Update**

If you only need one `a` element, then do this:

```
var post = $('.post').children('a[name]')[0].attr('name');
```

Make these changes when creating `href`:

```
easyface = $('<div />').addClass('easyface fb-like').attr({
    "data-href": settings.href.substring(0, settings.href.length - 1) + "#" + settings.post.split("p")[1], // concatenate with your href here.
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zUeFL/21/

Comment: No problem, jQuery can apply an attribute on a collection of objects.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati It can assign an attribute to multiple elements. But, cannot read them, it will only return the attribute of the first element in the array.

Comment: someone gave me a loop action to use but I couldn't figure it out and can not find it any more. :(

Comment: @EasyBB Loop action for what?

Comment: Loop through each post to do get each of the `a name="p843"` It is a forum based website so there will be multiple post. And it needs to get the closest a of the parent .post so when someone "likes" it facebook will link them to that comment

Comment: I need multiple post and do not want my users to write this 

` $('.postfoot').easyface({
        "post": pNames
    });`

Comment: So, you want to append a div for each post?

Comment: What should be the output of your plugin if you have `p001` and `p002`? By output, I mean, what should change in the HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're looking for: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jefferyto/HdLTF/)

The main changes are:

- The post ID is computed within the `each()` loop, since it will be different for each `.postfoot`:

  ```
  post = (options && options.post) || self.closest('.post').find('a:first').attr('name');
  ```

  This allows the post ID to be overridden by the `options` object, which may not be a good idea.
- The `easyface` div is also created within the `each()` loop, again because it will be different for each `.postfoot`.